# MySQL-cannot update view even though it shows as updatable

Tags: mysql, view, sql-update

I've created a view that `INNER JOINS` a bunch of tables but which would seem to still qualify to be updatable under MySQL rules, but updating data does not seem to work. Here is the view as shown in WorkBench:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
VIEW `event_registrants` AS
    SELECT 
        `event_details`.`DTT_EVT_start` AS `Event_Start`,
        `attendee_meta`.`ATT_email` AS `ATT_email`,
        `users`.`ID` AS `ID`,
        `user_detail_tbl`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
        `user_detail_tbl`.`nickname` AS `nickname`,
        `user_detail_tbl`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
        `registration`.`EVT_ID` AS `EVT_ID`,
        `posts`.`post_title` AS `post_title`,
        `misc_tbl`.`ANS_value` AS `ANS_value`
    FROM
        ((((((`misc_tbl`
        JOIN `registration` ON ((`misc_tbl`.`REG_ID` = `registration`.`REG_ID`)))
        JOIN `event_details` ON ((`registration`.`EVT_ID` = `event_details`.`EVT_ID`)))
        JOIN `posts` ON ((`posts`.`ID` = `registration`.`EVT_ID`)))
        JOIN `attendee_meta` ON ((`registration`.`ATT_ID` = `attendee_meta`.`ATT_ID`)))
        JOIN `users` ON ((`attendee_meta`.`ATT_email` = `users`.`user_email`)))
        JOIN `user_detail_tbl` ON ((`users`.`ID` = `user_detail_tbl`.`user_id`)))
```

According to mysqltutorial.org (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-updatable-views.aspx), one can check whether their views are updatable using

```
SELECT 
    table_name, 
    is_updatable
FROM
    information_schema.views
```

The output from the query indicates that my view is updatable (`is_updatable = YES`)

For some reason a simple update like:

```
UPDATE event_registrants
SET nickname='Terminator'
WHERE first_name='John';
```

yields `Error Code: 1288. The target table event registrants of the UPDATE is not updatable`.

Comment: To my way of thinking, views seem entirely pointless in MySQL. Just sayin'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any view to be updatable the engine should be able to match every resulting row to a **single base row** of the main/core table.

This is true on most database engines, not just MySQL. It's important to note that every database engine impose similar/extra requirements for updatable views.

In your particular case, you are using `INNER JOIN`s that [most likely] will result in multiple resulting rows related to each base row. Even if MySQL has marked it as updatable, it may not be able to do it.

Comment: Mysql marks a view updatatable if at least one of tables of the view can be updated.